# How to split a column which contains a combined text and number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table which consists of data like name50, somename20, other40, some65 like that.

I want to split the text part and number part and add the number part into another table with an empty column, which contains a column already with the text part. Now I have add the number part to the corresponding name part in this table.

For example in the second table I have a column called Textpart with the same text part from the first tables column (which I want to split) with all the names repeated several times randomly. And another caolumn called Numberpart which is empty.

Now I have to fill that numberpart with the corresponding numbers from the first table.

Please help me. thank you.

Comment: Look into the SUBSTRING and PATINDEX functions

Comment: Try pulling RIGHT(column,numcharacters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `patindex`.

First extract the numeric part. To get the text part just `replace` the previously found numeric part with an empty string.

```
select substring(data, patindex('%[0-9]%', data), len(data)) as numeric_part,
replace(data, substring(data, patindex('%[0-9]%', data), len(data)), '') as text_part
from tablename
```

To `update` the other table with the numeric part, use the text_part column to `join`.

Note that this will only work well if the numbers are towards the end.